# NPM LINQTS "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined" Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

**Typescript Environment**

TSConfig compiler options

```
"compilerOptions": {
"module": "amd",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"target": "es2016",
"lib": [
  "es2016",
  "dom"
],
```

Attempting to use *npm install linqts*

Throws error here at load time.. (Typescript compile worked fine)
[image: Throws Error Here]

Looking at Chrome's Sources tab shows:

[image: Chrome Source's Tab Shows Linqts]

Other modules use *export* which works fine.

What's best way to get this up and running? I don't understand other posts similar in nature to this one.  I tried changing es2015 to es5, it didn't work.

Should I Use babel, manually convert it, add dependencies in the linqts directory itself?